# A-frame building scene "inside cube"

Tags: aframe

I've just wanted to create a visualisation using A-frame library, in which user is "inside a cube" and on sides there are canvas images embedded. I've started preparing the scene using a-plane. That is what I've achived.
http://codepen.io/LuoXiahong/pen/LRNJNb

```
    <a-scene>
      <a-assets>
      </a-assets>
      <!-- Basic plane. -->
      <a-plane color="#ff0000" height="2" width="2" position="0 0 0" rotation="-90 0 0"></a-plane>
      <!-- Front-->
      <a-plane color="#00ff00" height="2" width="2" position="0 1 -1" rotation="0 0 90"></a-plane>
      <!--Back - does not display-->
      <a-plane color="#0000ff" height="2" width="2" position="0 1 1" rotation="0 0 90"></a-plane>
      <!-- Left-->
      <a-plane color="#ffff00" height="2" width="2" position="-1 1 0" rotation="0 90 0"></a-plane>
      <!-- Right-->
      <a-plane color="#ff00ff" height="2" width="2" position="1 1 0" rotation="0 -90 0"></a-plane>
      <!--Top plane - does not display -->
      <a-plane color="#00ffff" height="2" width="2" position="0 2 0" rotation="-90 0 0"></a-plane>
    </a-scene>
```

I have problem with displaying top and back side of my cube. Is there anyone, who could help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default in THREE.js (and therefore A-Frame), faces only render one side or the other. Your top plane is just rotated the wrong way, so it's only visible from the top. You can change its rotation to `90 0 0` to fix that, or add `side="back"` or `side="double"` to your `<a-plane />` to change which side(s) of the plane are shown. More details [here](https://aframe.io/docs/0.3.0/components/material.html#properties).

Comment: Might be `side="double"`